# Update JSON call

Tags: ajax, json

I'm pulling the current price of bitcoin from the Mt. Gox API. Here is a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Kx5N/6/ How do I get it to update regularly, like once per second?

Comment: `setInterval(function(){},1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Kx5N/7/

Just use setInterval(),javasctipt time function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Thanks Farkhad, that's perfect!